# How to loop until a specific output from curl command

Tags: linux, bash

I need to check if my tardis service is up and running after a patch.
To check i use the following command:

```
curl localhost:10100/status
```

The return will look like this:

```
{"buildInfo":{"buildTime":1623914298702,"name":"tardis","version":"2.6.0-177-g34f4189"}, "description":"Tardis service is fully functional.","name":"Running"}
```

Even if tardis is not up and running the command will return "0", as the command itself always finishes successful.

How can I build a loop that runs until either a counter reaches a specific value to make sure it doesn't run until kingdom come or until the return value from "curl" matches?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PLease show us your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: `curl` returns non-zero if it cannot connect.  Exactly which command are you using that "always finishes successful"?

Comment: curl localhost:10100/status. To elaborate. Even if tardis isn't up and running, the curl will return ""name":"Starting" instead of "name":"Running".  I haven't encountered, the the curl couldn't connect so far.
I have three sever where I need to check the status. Just running a script seems more efficient.

Comment: @0stone0: I don't have one. I can build one with a counter and a wait function, which is pretty basic, but that's all I'm able to do. I have no clue how to read from output and stop when I reach the correct output value.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of way to do this.

Trying a certain number of times -

```
for c in {1..5}; do curl -s localhost:10100/status | grep -o "Tardis service is fully functional." && break; done
```

Obviously, you could add a `sleep` in that loop if you want to space them out a bit, but `curl` gives it a couple second before timing out by default, and you could adjust that too.

If you want a specific time limit instead of a certain number of attempts -

```
limit=10; start=$SECONDS;
until (( limit < (SECONDS-start) )); do 
  curl -s localhost:10100/status | grep -o "Tardis service is fully functional." && break
done
```

I assume just checking `curl`'s return value isn't sufficient, because the service might successfully respond with a message other than *I'm up*?

If you want a more robust check on which you can base subsequent action -

```
chkStatus() { 
  local url="${1:-localhost:10100/status}"
  local msg="${2:-Tardis service is fully functional.}"
  local limit=${3:- 10} # can use this sort of setup with either logic       
  local pause=${4:- 1}
  local ret=1  # assume fail, reset for success on a hit
  local _      # only using as a counter
  for _ in $(seq $limit); do 
    if curl -s "$url" | grep -o "$msg"; then ret=0; break; fi
    sleep $pause
  done
  return $ret
}

chkStatus "$otherURL" "$otherMSG" "$otherLimit" "$otherPause" || echo FAIL
```

I turned on debugging output when I tested it -

```
$: set -x; chkStatus "$otherURL" "$otherMSG" "$otherLimit" "$otherPause" || echo FAIL; set +x
+ chkStatus google.com bogus 2 0.25
+ local url=google.com
+ local msg=bogus
+ local limit=2
+ local pause=0.25
+ local ret=1
+ local _
++ seq 2
+ for _ in $(seq $limit)
+ curl -s google.com
+ grep --color -o bogus
+ sleep 0.25
+ for _ in $(seq $limit)
+ curl -s google.com
+ grep --color -o bogus
+ sleep 0.25
+ return 1
+ echo FAIL
FAIL
+ set +x

$: set -x; chkStatus "$otherURL" "$otherMSG" || echo FAIL; set +x
+ chkStatus google.com 'The document has moved'
+ local url=google.com
+ local 'msg=The document has moved'
+ local 'limit= 10'
+ local 'pause= 1'
+ local ret=1
+ local _
++ seq 10
+ for _ in $(seq $limit)
+ curl -s google.com
+ grep --color -o 'The document has moved'
The document has moved
+ ret=0
+ break
+ return 0
+ set +x
```

Using full URL and a nonbogus message WITHOUT debug mode -

```
$: time chkStatus http://www.google.com/ CSS1Compat || echo "Google says no."
CSS1Compat

real    0m0.324s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.154s
```

With a not-found message -

```
$: time chkStatus http://www.google.com/ "Anyone home?" 3 .5 || echo "Google says no."

real    0m2.580s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.399s
Google says no.
```

(Note the success message comes before the `time` output as it's inside the function, but the fail message is after since it's not.)

Google *does* respond, but the function behaves accordingly if the requested message exists or doesn't.

Comment: That is correct. It can display messages like "_starting_" or "_not running_"
That's the reason I can't use the return value. That would have been easier.

Comment: **WOW**.
I adjusted the script to my needs, but this I'll definitly use as a base for scripts with a lot more depth. Thanks a lot!